# Hyper-V Ubuntu 10.04 Server Hard Disk Size

Tags: linux, hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server on Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V. I have setup a hard drive that is 400GB. Yet every time I try to install it only recognizes it as a 136gb drive.

I have tried the following:

SCSI HD vs IDE HD

Fixed vs Dynamic disk

Diff SCSI and IDE channels

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: 136GB (127GiB) is the pre-ATA/100 interface limit if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as this and found the solution here:
http://fawzi.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/ubuntu-server-10-4-in-hyper-v/

Although this article is about the synthetic NIC and how to use that instead of the legacy driver it also worked for the larger drive. I created a small VHD and added it to the IDE Controller as the root partition to boot from as /dev/hda1 and then created a big VHD and added it to the SCSI Controller. When the drive was mounted it showed the full space available in fdisk.

If the hv_ modules are not loaded then I could not see the drive as a device at all.

NOTE: If you follow the above website instructions to use Synthetic NIC then you'll also need this article:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9876653

As the synthetic NIC didn't work for me until I did the above.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Hyper-V but try something more related to the virtual BIOS or controller settings like 48-bit LBA.

Comment: All the BIOS settings seem to work fine. Also with CentOS the hard drive size shows up fine. So it is only Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: It's also Debian